# Asp.Net MVC - HTML.ActionLink - HowToGoTo - Client/Index/A - route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is in my route (works)

```
    routes.MapRoute("ClientIndexAndSubstringChar", _
                    "{controller}/{action}/{FirstChar}", _
                    New With {.char = "[a-zA-Z0-9]"})
```

This is in my controller (works)

```
   Function Index(Optional ByVal KlantenSet As List(Of Domain.Slave.Klant) = Nothing, Optional FirstChar As Char = Nothing, Optional format As String = "html") As ActionResult
     //Some Code
    End Function
```

This is my View (doesn't link correctly)

```
@If ViewBag.ClientsLetters IsNot Nothing Then
  For Each ClientLetter As String In ViewBag.ClientsLetters
    @<div class="ClientsLetter">
      @Html.ActionLink(ClientLetter, "Index", "Client", New With {.FirstChar = ClientLetter})
    </div>
   Next
 End If
```

The ActionLink is wrong....

What should i do to fix it?
My link links to : 
       http://localhost:52254/Client/Index.html?Length=6
Instead of
        http://localhost:52254/Client/Index/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action link

```
@Html.ActionLink(ClientLetter, "Index", "Client", New With {.FirstChar = ClientLetter})
```

The parameters here match this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx

Should be something like this

```
@Html.ActionLink(ClientLetter, "Index", "Client", New With {.FirstChar = ClientLetter}, Null)
```

These parameters match this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068.aspx

For the MapRoute I think you can do this:

```
routes.MapRoute("ClientIndexAndSubstringChar", _
                "{controller}/{action}/{FirstChar}")
```

Just get rid of that last parameter. Try it and see what it does.

Comment: You are right, but it is displaying http://localhost:52254/Client/Index.html?FirstChar=A , is it hard to display it as http://localhost:52254/Client/Index/A ? Because the route to that works... :)

Comment: I'm a little unfamiliar with VB, so this is a little bit harder. If you want it to look that way, you need to do something in the MapRoute for it to display that way. ActionLink's link is based on that MapRoute I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the work. I changed my routers and i changed /Client/Index/A to /Client/A to make it easier and everything is working fine now. Thanks!